# Why can't I cast an array to AnyObject in a notification?

Tags: swift, nsnotificationcenter

I have an array of RequestError that I'd like to pass to a notification userInfo object.

```
let errors: [RequestError]
let errorDictionary = ["errors": errors]
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().notificationCenter.postNotificationName(UserSaveFailKey, object: self, userInfo: errorDictionary)
```

Why am I getting

> Cannot convert value of type '[String : [RequestError]]' to expected
>   argument type '[NSObject : AnyObject]?'

Comment: I suspect your problem is that `RequestError` is a `struct`.  An array of `struct` cannot be converted to `NSArray` and thus it can't be an `AnyObject`.

Comment: It won't work if `RequestError` is an `enum` either.  It needs to be a reference type, i.e. a `class`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `RequestError` is an `enum` or a `struct`, then it isn't a reference type and an array of them will not conform to `AnyObject` because it can't be converted to `NSArray`.

You could work around this by creating a wrapper class:

```
class RequestErrorsWrapper {
    let errors: [RequestError]

    init(errors: [RequestError]) {
        self.errors = errors
    }
}

let errorDictionary = ["errors": RequestErrorsWrapper(errors: errors)]
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(UserSaveFailKey, object: self, userInfo: errorDictionary)
```

Then on the receiving end, you'd unpack the errors like this:

```
    if let wrapper = notification.userInfo?["errors"] as? RequestErrorsWrapper {
        let errors = wrapper.errors
        // use errors
    }
```